# Gear icon instead of App icon in taskbar

Tags: icons, taskbar, pyqt5

I made a .desktop file for a PyQt5 App, it does show the icon on the desktop, but when I open it and starts running, the icon is not showed in the taskbar, instead there is a gear icon. Thanks for your help

.desktop file:

```
[Desktop Entry]
StartupWMClass=esmeralda_suites.py
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Name=Esmeralda Software
Comment=
Exec='/home/cattivellio/Documents/Esmeralda BETA 9/esmeralda_suites.py'
Icon=/home/cattivellio/Documents/Esmeralda BETA 9/img/minilogo.png
Path=/home/cattivellio/Documents/Esmeralda BETA 9
Terminal=false
StartupNotify=true
```

[desktop screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ybrhe.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

You will need to specify the correct wmclass in the `.desktop launcher.

- Look up the wmclass for your window: for the standard Ubuntu desktop, open the run dialog (<kbd>lt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>) while the app is running. Type `lg` followed by Enter, and look up the wmclass of the app in the list.
- Then add or edit the key `StartupWMClass` in the `.desktop launcher such that it mentions the correct wmclass.

  ```
  StartupWMClass=<wmclass>
  ```

Comment: I got this: `WM_CLASS(STRING) = "esmeralda_suites.py", "esmeralda_suites.py"
`, but when I add it on my .desktop file it like this `StartupWMClass=esmeralda_suites.py` I still missing the icon in the taskbar, I also tried like this `StartupWMClass="esmeralda_suites.py"` and like this `StartupWMClass=<esmeralda_suites.py>`

Comment: So you are running Xorg. Still, the trick should work, especially after you restarted the system. Indeed, the first version is the correct one, although it may also work with the quotes.

Comment: I already restarted the system and still the same problem, Im going to add my .desktop file to the question

Answer (score 0):

The first answer is correct if it is showing no icon.  However, if you are seeing a gear, look somewhere else in your Applications View, and you will likely find a gear icon with a similar name.

When you launch from the Applications View it is somehow loading that gear icon .desktop entry instead.  Find that .desktop entry, probably in /usr/share/applications, remove it, make sure you follow the setup instructions above, and it will work.